# Retrieve anonymous PLSQL block result

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have some trouble retrieving the result of an anonymous PLSQL block in java.

Here is the block :

```
DECLARE
in_cnt_date DATE := '&1';
hv_cnt_id NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE (NULL);
INSERT INTO dt_contexts
(CNT_ID, CNT_CONTEXT, CNT_TYPE, CNT_SOURCE, CNT_COMMENT, CNT_DATE, CNT_DATE_INSERT, CNT_DATE_UPDATE)
VALUES
(0, 'EPE_CONTEXT', 'ROUTE', 'bdd', 'Built from ROUTE', in_cnt_date, SYSDATE, SYSDATE);

SELECT SEQ_DT_CNT_ID.CURRVAL
INTO hv_cnt_id
FROM DUAL;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE ;
END;
```

I put that query in a String :

```
public static final String CONTEXT = "DECLARE in_cnt__date DATE := '&1'; " +
"hv_cnt_id NUMBER := 0; " +
"BEGIN DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE (NULL); " +
"INSERT INTO dt_contexts (CNT_ID, CNT_CONTEXT, CNT_TYPE, CNT_SOURCE, CNT_COMMENT, CNT_DATE, CNT_DATE_INSERT, CNT_DATE_UPDATE) " +
"VALUES (0, 'EPE_CONTEXT', 'ROUTE', 'bdd', 'Built from ROUTE', ?, SYSDATE, SYSDATE); " +
"SELECT SEQ_DT_CNT_ID.CURRVAL INTO hv_cnt_id FROM DUAL; " +
"EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE ; END;";
```

Is that String correct ?

The method which tries to retrieve `hv_cnt_id` :

```
public int getContextId(Connection conn) throws Exception {
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    int contextId = 0;
    try {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        cs = conn.prepareCall(CONTEXT);
        cs.setDate(1, (java.sql.Date) Route.datePrf);

        cs.execute();
        contextId = (Integer) cs.getObject(1);

        conn.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        close(rs, cs);
    }
    return contextId;
}
```

It does'nt work, as I get this message :

`java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-06512: at line 1`

So how do I retrieve `hv_cnt_id` ?

Comment: Remove all exception handlers and execute the block and yiu will see the exact line number where the error occurs.

Comment: It is because the implicit date conversion is failing. Add `TO_DATE()` instead of directly assigning the date string to a date variable. The implicit conversion usually depends on the session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

Comment: Looks like you're attempting to pass parameters to an anonymous block, which I think is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the *implicit* date conversion is failing. Add `TO_DATE()` instead of directly assigning the date string to a date variable. If `java.sql.Date` is used, the `TO_DATE()` is not required.

The implicit conversion usually depends on the session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

In your case `in_cnt__date DATE := '&1'` is the culprit. `&1` will actually be attempted to convert into a date.. And hence the exception thrown!

```
public static final String CONTEXT = "DECLARE in_cnt__date DATE := ? ;" +
"hv_cnt_id NUMBER := 0; " +
"BEGIN DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE (NULL); " +
"INSERT INTO dt_contexts (CNT_ID, CNT_CONTEXT, CNT_TYPE, CNT_SOURCE, CNT_COMMENT, CNT_DATE, CNT_DATE_INSERT, CNT_DATE_UPDATE) " +
"VALUES (0, 'EPE_CONTEXT', 'ROUTE', 'bdd', 'Built from ROUTE', in_cnt__date, SYSDATE, SYSDATE); " +
"SELECT SEQ_DT_CNT_ID.CURRVAL INTO hv_cnt_id FROM DUAL; " +
"? := hv_cnt_id;
"EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE ; END;";
```

And then,

```
cs.setDate(1, (java.sql.Date) Route.datePrf);
```

Will set the date for `in_cnt__date`;

Finally, to retreive the values in `hv_cnt_id`
The below is added to your `PL/SQL` block

```
"? := hv_cnt_id;"
```

And from JDBC, we get it like,

```
 cs.setDate(1, (java.sql.Date) Route.datePrf);
 cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.NUMBER);
 cs.execute();
 contextId = cs.getInt(2);
```

Comment: Index is wrong, but also why not: `contextId = cs.getInt(2);` ?

Comment: yes Alex, you are right. I just used the same code of OP's.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all `exception` handlers from the `PL/SQL` code, and execute the block and you will see the exact line number where the error occurs.

`Raise` inside exception will never let you know the **exact error details**. Please read http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/when-others-then-null-a-bug/ Focus on the `RAISE` part.

Once you do it, you will find that there is an `data type` conversion issue.