# Invalid column index in anonymous plsql block

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I am getting an `Invalid column index` when I try to set a parameter `in_cnt_date` of this query :

```
public static final String CONTEXT = "DECLARE in_cnt_date DATE := TO_DATE('&'); " +
" hv_cnt_id NUMBER := 0; " +
" BEGIN DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE (NULL); " +
" INSERT INTO dt_contexts (CNT_ID, CNT_CONTEXT, CNT_TYPE, CNT_SOURCE, CNT_COMMENT, CNT_DATE, CNT_DATE_INSERT, CNT_DATE_UPDATE) VALUES (0, 'EPE_CONTEXT', 'ROUTE', 'bdd', 'Built from ROUTE', in_cnt_date, SYSDATE, SYSDATE); " +
" SELECT SEQ_DT_CNT_ID.CURRVAL INTO hv_cnt_id FROM DUAL; " +
" dbms_output.put_line(hv_cnt_id); " +
" EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE ; END;";
```

The setting of the parameter :

```
CallableStatement cs = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    int contextId = 0;
    try {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        cs = conn.prepareCall(CONTEXT);
        cs.setDate(1, (java.sql.Date) Route.datePrf);
```

Can you help ?

Comment: This looks same as your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182869/retrieve-anonymous-plsql-block-result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current statement does not have any bind variables, so when you try to bind index 1, you get this error. The bind variable placeholder is a question mark, not an ampersand, and should not be quoted:

```
"DECLARE in_cnt_date DATE := TO_DATE(?); " +
```

But you're setting it using a `Date`, so you don't need the `TO_DATE()` call:

```
"DECLARE in_cnt_date DATE := ?; " +
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to input a Character Datatype to TO_DATE Function

Please refer the link [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions191.htm)

```
The TO_DATE function converts char of CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, or NVARCHAR2 datatype to a value of DATE datatype
```